# How can I use only the root layout from a live view template in Phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-live-view

Mainly I want to get rid of the

```html
<main role="main" class="container">
```

tag surrounding the rest of the page. That's defined in `live.html.leex` so I thought I could exclude it by putting this line into `router.ex`:

```
    live "/watch/:guest_id", WatchLive, layout: {MyAppWeb.LayoutView, :root}
```

It's still there though. How can I exclude `live.html.leex`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow this up it's worth noting for the next person; :put_root_layout plug in the :browser pipeline in router.ex can end up causing two layouts (live view and a root layout).

I wanted these to be different so I've added a :browser pipeline without the :put_root_layout and another :layout pipeline with just that.

So I have :browser and :browser_with_layout which extends it.

Answer (score -1):

As a first idea you can just change it if it's not affecting to other pages)

But seriously, you can use put_layout from Phoenix in your controller.
Try that:

> https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#put_layout/2